# Windows sandbox does not run .NET apps

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-sandbox

when I try to run any .NET app it fails with following error in image.

[image]

Windows features list is also empty

[image]

Tried deleting kb 4506991 but still the same

Comment: trusted installer / Windows module installer is needed to configure updates/features.

Comment: It's in windows sandbox not a host machine.It's a known issue

Comment: ok, I can't even run Sandbox at all (German Windows causes  "ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (0x80070002)"), so I can't test it at all

Comment: I would be also interested in knowing if the Windows Features will be enabled. Tried PowerShell to install IIS but the commands return "The system cannot find the path specified." I guess it does not allow access to Sandbox as a target for commands ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in latest cumulative update of windows 10.Net apps now working fine

Comment: My system is fully up to date and I just ran into this issue. Looks like it has not been fixed

Comment: now it's broken again... on Windows 11 22H2 (KB5020044)