# How to enable the 'NET FRAMEWORK 3.5' feature in the SANDBOX?

Tags: virtual, .net-4.8

I need to use an application that requires the 'NET FRAMEWORK 3.5' feature, and when trying to install the feature, the errors in the image below occur.

[Error instalation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9hJG.png)

[Windows resources reset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNMIR.png)

As per the question in the link below, it had been fixed; however, another user below the response mentions that the error has recurred and they haven't received any further answers.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56999667/windows-sandbox-does-not-run-net-apps?newreg=332ae85d7e0747509c7e72313935c740)

We attempted to use the tutorial from the link below to create a configuration file and initiate the sandbox with the feature already installed, but we didn't achieve success.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-configure-an-app-to-support-net-framework-4-or-4-5

Having the '.wsb' file as follows:

```
<Configuration>
<Networking>Default</Networking>
<ClipboardRedirection>Default</ClipboardRedirection>
<MemoryInMB>2048</MemoryInMB>
<MappedFolders>
   <MappedFolder>
     <HostFolder>C:\teste</HostFolder>
     <SandboxFolder>C:\teste</SandboxFolder> 
     <ReadOnly>True</ReadOnly>
   </MappedFolder>
</MappedFolders>
<LogonCommand>
      <Command>C:\teste\Instala.exe </Command>
</LogonCommand>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7" />
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />   
    </startup>
</Configuration>
```